# MySQL Error 1064 - but no misstake?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'dont understand this:

I will update a mysql database.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE image Set title = '".$ed1."', desc = '".$ed2."', cat = '".$ed3."', privacy = '".$ed4."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");
```

But it shows:

> ERROR 1064

and:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near desc = [...]

**EDIT:**
Thanks for reply. I've renamed the name! Now it works ;)

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_* API anymore. It is being deprecated by the community. It's highly insecure and inefficient. Use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements instead.

Comment: +1 for suggesting switching to PDO, I recently fell in love with executing SQL this way.  Also, instead of quoting off the desc field, I would recommend altering the name, so that you don't have any future problems with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DESC is a reserved word in SQL. You'll need to quote it if you want to use it:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `image` Set `title` = '".$ed1."', `desc` = '".$ed2."', `cat` = '".$ed3."', `privacy` = '".$ed4."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");
```

You should try to avoid using reserved words for field names if you can; there's a list here:
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

You should also look at migrating from `mysql_*` functions, as they're being deprecated. You should look at using PDO or mysqli instead - they both help you write much more secure SQL.

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_* API anymore. It is being deprecated by the community. It's highly insecure and inefficient. Use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements instead.

Comment: @markus-tharkun: it's not "insecure". it can be just as secure as mysqli or pdo. there's nothing about mysqli/pdo that make them more secure. you can write the exact same injection-vulnerable code in mysqli and pdo. Please stop the fear mongering.

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You need to escape it with backticks. Try

```
UPDATE image Set title = '".$ed1."', `desc` = ...
```